# Marginal probability

Tags: probability

The random variables X and Y.

DELETED... AS IT IS OFF TOPIC.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_X$ and $f_Y$ denote the marginal probabilities of $P(X=x)$ and $P(Y=y)$.

The probability over the domain must add up to 1.

$$1=\sum_{x=1}^a \sum_{y=1}^{2a-2x} c (2x+y)= \sum_{x=1}^a f_x =\sum_{x=1}^a c(a-x)(2x+2a-1) $$

We get $$1=\frac{ac}{6}(a-1)(8a+5)$$ or 
$$ c=\frac{6}{a(a-1)(8a+5)}$$

Since we have noted that $f_X=c(a-x)(2x+2-1)$, knowing the value of $c$, we immediately get the expression you have.

The marginal probability for Y is given by

$$P(Y=y)=\sum_{x=1}^{a-\frac{y}{2}} c (2x+y)=c(a^2-\frac{y^2}{4})$$

Plug in the value of $c$ you have and you are done.

Note: The calculations above used the two formulas

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2};  \sum_{k=1}^n k^2= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

First calculate $c$ by using that the sum over all possible $x,y$ of the joint probablity has to be $1$

So: $$\sum_{3 \le 2x+y \le 2a} P(X=x,Y = y) = 1$$

has to hold.
So we get:
$$\begin{align*} \sum_{3 \le 2x+y \le 2a} P(X=x,Y = y) &= \sum_{x=1}^{a-1}\sum_{y=1}^{2(a-x)}c(2x + y) =c\sum_{x=1}^{a-1}\sum_{y=1}^{2(a-x)}(2x + y) = 1\end{align*}$$

Hence $$c = \frac{1}{\sum_{x=1}^{a-1}\sum_{y=1}^{2(a-x)}(2x + y)}$$

The marginal probability $P(X=x)$ can be calculated as the sum of $P(X=x,Y=y)$ for all possible values of $y$.

The restrictions for $y$ are $y\ge 1$ and $2x+y \le 2a$ hence $y \le 2(a-x)$

So written as a formula:

$$\begin{align*}P(X = x) &= \sum_{y=1}^{2(a-x)}P(X=x,Y=y) \\ &= \sum_{y=1}^{2(a-x)} c(2x + y) \\ &= 2cx \sum_{y=1}^{2(a-x)} 1 +  c\sum_{y=1}^{2(a-x)}y \\ &= 4cx(a-x) + c(a-x)(2a-2x+1) \end{align*}$$

The same you can do with the marginal of $P(Y=y)$